# tengo un problema la relacion entre un controller y un view

Tags: php, laravel, json

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Discapacidad;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DiscapacidadController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($tipo)
    {
        return view('discapacidad.index', ["tipo" => $tipo]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Educacion  $educacion
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Discapacidad $discapacidad)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Educacion  $educacion
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Discapacidad $discapacidad)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Educacion  $educacion
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Discapacidad $discapacidad)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Educacion  $educacion
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Discapacidad $discapacidad)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Ese el el archivo Controller

y este el archivo web.php

```
Route::get('discapacidad/{tipo}','DiscapacidadController@index')->name('discapacidad.index')->middleware('auth');
```

también están cargados los archivo discapacidad.blade.php y el discapacidad-escuelas.php

El navegador me arroja este mensaje:

> Livewire\Exceptions\ComponentNotFoundException
> Unable to find component: [discapacidad]

[imagen de pantalla de error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9ucf.png)

[image: imagen de misma pantalla]

Comment: Te esta avisando de un componente que no encuentra, preguntas: ¿si lo creaste?, ¿estás seguro del nombre?, ¿el componente lo invocas directo en el archivo de vistas o lo invocas a través de dicho controller?, debes proveer mas detalles

Comment: Hola! que componente es el que me avisa que no encuentra? revise cada uno y no logro detectar cual es.

Comment: El texto en azul te indica de forma clara que componente no encuentra

Comment: Cuando estás mandando a llamar a la `vista` estás diciendo que vaya a la carpeta `discapacidad` y muestre la vista `index.blade.php`, la variable que envías después no sé si este bien ese formato (no entiendo muy bien como envía el dato ahí) pero porque no usas `compact` si solo quieres enviar la variable `$tipo` a tu vista. Si estas en laravel 8 podrías cambiar tu route (ya que así se usaba antes) por este formato: `Route::get('discapacidad/{tipo}', [DiscapacidadController::class, 'index'])->name('discapacidad.index');`.

Comment: Copie el formato sugerido y ahora directamente no abre la web..... te muestro la ruta del adminlte.  [
            'text'    => 'Discapacidad',
            'icon'    => 'fas fa-fw fas fa-wheelchair', 
            'submenu' => [

                [
                    'text'    => 'Establecimientos Educativos',
                    'icon'    => 'fas fa-regular fa-caret-right',
                    'route' => ['discapacidad.index', ['tipo' => 'discapacidad-escuelas']],

Comment: sigo en la misma, como hago?

Comment: El error te dice que Livewire no encuentra un componente, pero en tu pregunta no hay ninguna mención a Livewire. Significa que estás intentando incluir un componente en la vista, pero ese es justo el código que no pusiste.  Por favor edita tu pregunta añadiéndolo. También serviría mucho entender la estructura de  tu carpeta `resources/views`. Un pantallazo con el árbol de subdirectorios y archivos serviría.